# How do you prevent chicken from sticking when searing?

Tags: chicken, meat, searing

My method of making stewed chicken is to sear the outside, take the chicken out, add veggies, saute, THEN add the chicken and cook until its ready. That way the chicken gets a sear and is not overcooked.

But when I flip or take out the chicken the skin just sticks to the pan. If I will deglaze using wine, it will lower the temperature of the pan, making it harder to get a sear before the inside gets over well done.

Comment: Are you oiling the pan?

Comment: Yes. At least three tbsp of fat

Answer (score 9):

Use a heavy bottomed pan. Heat pan medium high.  Add oil.  Place chicken skin side down.  Don't move the chicken.  Once you see browning, gently see if the chicken releases.  If it does not, leave it.  It should release with some gentle nudging, but it should not be moved if it doesn't release.  Usually the issue arises when the meat is flipped or removed too soon.